# WooCommerce get_available_variations when variation is set to Any

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an interesting case where `get_available_variations` is not working properly.

I have a variable product **socks** and this product has 1 attribute **size** with 3 terms selected **X M XL**. The product has only one variation which is set to "ANY" (instead of 3 variations).

I am trying to create a script which should export some data about the products, however when I try `get_available_variations` function, it returns:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(25) {
    ["attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["attribute_pa_size"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

which seems to be correct for this case (in admin value for ANY is empty string). I've tried visiting the single page of that product and woocommerce correctly shows up all 3 variations.

I have other variable products that have variations set for each variation and they show up correctly.

Do you have any other idea how can I generate a list with all 3 variations?

My code so far:

```
$products = wc_get_products(array(
    'status' => 'publish',
    'limit' => -1,
));

if ($products) {
    echo '<products>';
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        echo '<product>';
        echo '<id>'. $product->get_id() .'</id>';
        echo '<title>'. esc_html(strip_tags($product->get_title())) .'</title>';
        echo '<description>'. esc_html(str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $product->get_short_description())) .'</description>';
        echo '<price>'. $product->get_sale_price() .'</price>';
        echo '<old_price>'. $product->get_regular_price() .'</old_price>';
        echo '<sku>'. esc_html($product->get_sku()) .'</sku>';
            
        if ($product->get_type() == 'variable') {
            $product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
            
            echo '<options>';
            
            foreach ($product_variations as $variation) {
                echo "<option>
                    {";
                    foreach ($variation['attributes'] as $key=>$value) {
                        $taxonomy = str_replace('attribute_', '', $key);
                        $term = get_term_by('slug', $value, $taxonomy);
                        echo "
                        'label' : '". wc_attribute_label($taxonomy) ."',
                        'value' : '". $term->name ."',
                        ";
                    }
                echo "
                    'sku' : '". $variation['sku'] ."',
                    'weight' : '". (!empty($variation['weight']) ? $variation['weight'] : 0) ."',
                    'quantity' : ". ($variation['is_purchasable'] === true ? 10 : 0) .",
                    'image' : '". $variation['image']['url'] ."',
                    'price' : ". $variation['display_regular_price'] .",
                    'discounted_price' : ". $variation['display_price'] ."
                    }
                </option>
                ";
            }
            
            echo '</options>';
        }
        echo '</product>';
    }
    echo '</products>';
}
```